# Passing a Lua variable to C

Tags: c++, c, lua

I am embedding Lua in a C++ application and I want to provide a print() like function (or maybe simply override Lua's print function), so that I can pass variables of simple datatypes (string, boolean and number) into my C++ app as strings.

So what I am looking to do is to have a C++ function, which I export to Lua, called my_print()

I can then call my_print() in a Lua chunk like so:

```
a = 22/7
b = false
c = 42
my_print('The value of variable a is: ' .. a)
my_print('b: ' .. b)
my_print('c is: ' .. c)
```

Each time my_print() is called, it will pass a C++ string to the C++ app. I have had a look at the Lua C API, I suspect that I will have to use lua_gettop(L), lua_type() etc.

A little snippet on how to get started in writing such a C/C++ function that can be exported to Lua and used in the manner described above, would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

Have you looked at the implementation of `print` and other functions from the standard Lua library? You may want to start with `lmathlib.c`. See http://www.lua.org/source/5.1/ . Try also `etc/min.c` from the source tarball.

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look at this http://www.lua.org/source/5.1/lbaselib.c.html#luaB_tostring

Here they are returning the string but it is a good starting point.  I can't really disagree with lhf but this deals with the meta table's __tostring while min.c does not.  I think that is pretty important, especially when you get into Lua oo.

Answer (score 0):

If you do it like you have in your example, the one argument `my_print` gets is already a string (or better lua_lstring), because the values get coerced to the string type by the concatenation operator `..`. Only the `false` thing won't work. so just passing `tostring(var)` will work in most cases. For more control you might take a look at `string.format`.